# Python user input with fractions

Tags: python, fractions

I am new programming and I am a bit stumped on this assignment. We are supposed to take user input of two fractions and get the product or quotient. We went over defining functions and I have those done but I am stumped on how to refer them to user input and vise-versa. Any pointers or clues would be appreciated, I just need some sort of epiphany I think. Here is my embarrassing code:

```
import fractions

def gcd(m,n):

    while m%n != 0: #finds the GCD (global definition)
        oldm = m
        oldn = n

        m = oldn
        n = oldm%oldn
    return n

class Fraction:

    def __init__(self,top,bottom): #constructor; creating fraction

        self.num = top      #methods to go about placing numerator and denominator
        self.den = bottom

    def __str__(self): #calling the fraction from methods above
        return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den) #Returns the value of fraction


    def __add__(self,otherfraction): #For addition of fractions (self = first fraction, otherfraction = second fraction)

        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)

        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common) #Returns the new fraction with reduced answer.


    def __mul__(self,otherfraction): #For multiplication of fractions

        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den*otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)

        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)


    def __floordiv__(self,otherfraction): #For division of fractions; use // not /

        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den #Use multiplication of the reciprocal
        newden = self.den*otherfraction.num
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)

        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)


    def __sub__(self,otherfraction): #For subtraction of fractions

        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den - self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)

        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your program, you'll need to get some input from the user and then you'll likely need to modify that input so that you can instantiate your Fraction objects with that input. In Python2.x getting input from a user normally looks like this:

```
some_user_entered_string = raw_input()
```

You should try this in the Python interpreter. Try a bunch of variations and see what happens. Anyway, in Python3.x it normally looks like this:

```
some_user_entered_string = input()
```

You can also print something so that the user knows what to enter, as in the following example:

```
some_user_entered_string = input("Please enter a fraction: ")
```

Again: you should try this in your Python interpreter.

Notice two things: 1) the value being entered is assigned to my variable `some_user_entered_string` and 2) it is going to be a string, so if you want to do number-like stuff with it you'll need to convert it.

Comment: I understand how to call or initiate an input but what I don't get is how to associate what I am inputting (e.g. two numbers (1, 2) ) with the functions I have in place. The functions iterate fine when I invoke a fraction through the shell (e.g.  f1=Fraction(1,2) ) but when creating a user input I would have to make it so when entering two numbers they are understood by the computer as A over B not A and B. I will take what you said into account, thank you.

Comment: I figured that would be a kind of key step and I figured it would be more useful to struggle through it and figure it out. Based on the class, you need to probably grab two values from a user, 'numerator' and 'denominator'. Once you have those, you'll need to turn them into integers or floats and then throw the variables directly into your functions. That should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will help or not (if it doesn't, let me know and I'll remove the answer) Is also not a direct answer to your question, but it might help (might)

There are two parts in the example. One, the capture of an string entered by the user, and after that, using regular expressions to "parse" the user input:

```
>>> import re
>>> re_fraction=re.compile(r"(?P<top>\d+)/(?P<bottom>\d+)$")
>>> fraction_str = raw_input()
3/4
>>> groups = re_fraction.match(fraction_str).groupdict()
>>> groups
{'top': '3', 'bottom': '4'}
>>> f = Fraction(groups['top'], groups['bottom'])
```

To understand what this is doing, please check:

1. how to capture user input in a terminal: [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)
2. the re module in general: [re (1)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)
3. matches with regular expressions: [re module (2)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)
4. an [online regular expression tester](http://www.pythonregex.com/)